# static_assert evaluates non constant expression

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

Why does it working?

```
#include <cstdio>

template<auto x> struct constant {
  constexpr operator auto() { return x; }
};
constant<true> true_;

static constexpr const bool true__ = true;

template<auto tag> struct registryv2 {
  // not constexpr
  static auto push() {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    //*
    return true_; // compiles
    /*/
    return true__; // read of non-const variable 'x' is not allowed in a constant expression
    //*/
  }
  // not constexpr either
  static inline auto x = push();
};

static_assert(registryv2<0>::x);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GYTdE3M9q

Comment: @paddy x is static field, not a function

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake and had already deleted my comment before you replied.

Comment: Your conversion operator will trigger if you use `this`.

Comment: Aside: names with consecutive underscores anywhere, are reserved for the implementation. Please don't use names like that in your programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> static_assert evaluates non constant expression

Nope, it most certainly does not. Constant evaluation has a strict set of conditions to is must obey in order to succeed.

For starters:

> **[dcl.dcl]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#6) In a static_assert-declaration, the constant-expression shall be a contextually converted constant expression of type bool.

"contextually converted" is standard lingo for "we'll consider explicit conversion operators". The place where it may become counter-intuitive is when "converted constant expression" is defined.

> **[expr.const]**
>
> [4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#4) A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only
>
> - user-defined conversions,
> - [...]

The fine point is in the first sentence of the paragraph. The *converted expression* must be a constant expression. But the *source* expression doesn't have to be! So long as the conversion sequence is limited to the list in the paragraph and is valid constant evaluation itself, we are in the clear. In your example, the expression `registryv2<0>::x` has type `constant<true>`, it can be contextually converted to a `bool` via the user defined conversion operator. And well, the conversion operator satisfiers all the requirements of a constexpr function and constant evaluation.

The [list of requirements for constant evaluation is rather long](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2) so I won't go over it to verify every bullet is upheld. But I will demonstrate that we can trip one of them.

```
template<auto x> struct constant {
  bool const x_ = x;
  constexpr explicit operator auto() const { return x_; }
};
```

This change [immediately makes the godbolt code sample ill-formed](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:55,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:55,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:55,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:55,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Cauto+x%3E+struct+constant+%7B%0A++bool+const+x_+%3D+x%3B%0A++constexpr+explicit+operator+auto()+const+%7B+return+x_%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Aconstexpr+constant%3Ctrue%3E+true_%3B%0A%0Astatic+constexpr+const+bool+true__+%3D+true%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Cauto+tag%3E+struct+registryv2+%7B%0A++static+auto+push()+%7B%0A++++fprintf(stderr,+%22%25s%5Cn%22,+__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)%3B%0A%0A++++//*%0A++++return+true_%3B+//+compiles%0A++++/*/%0A++++return+true__%3B+//+read+of+non-const+variable+!%27x!%27+is+not+allowed+in+a+constant+expression%0A++++//*/%0A++%7D%0A%0A++static+inline+auto+x+%3D+push()%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert(registryv2%3C0%3E::x)%3B%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+%3D+void%3E%0A+struct+objectv2+%7B%0A++void+a()+%7B%0A++++static_assert(registryv2%3C%26objectv2::a%3E::x)%3B%0A++%7D%0A++void+b()+%7B%0A++++static_assert(registryv2%3C%26objectv2::b%3E::x)%3B%0A++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0Avoid+test_registryv2()+%7B%0A++objectv2+o%3B%0A++o.a()%3B%0A//o.b()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1300,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-pedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+13.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). Why? Because we are doing an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (standard lingo for access) on a `bool` when it is not permitted.

> An expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of integral or enumeration type that refers to a complete non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a subobject of a string literal, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers to a non-mutable subobject of such an object, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of e;

Going over the exceptions, none apply. So now `registryv2<0>::x` is not a contextually converted constant expression of type `bool`.

This also explain why `true__`<sup>1</sup> is verboten. Same issue, access to an object that is disallowed.

---

<sup>1</sup> - That's a reserved identifier. Two consecutive underscores belong to the implementation for any use. Not critical to the issue at hand, but take note.

Comment: `fprintf` is not `constexpr`, so how does it initializes `registryv2::x` for `static_assert`?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic - I clearly stated that `registryv2::x` prior to the conversion doesn't have to be a constant expression.

Comment: I don't understand to which object refers `this` inside static assertion (`constexpr explicit operator auto() const { *this; return x; }`). How it can assert on value not yet constructed?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic - Who said it's not constructed? It is. The static assertion must be able to **convert** it to a constant expression without breaking any constraint. And your conversion operator does exactly that.

Comment: As I understand your answer `static_assert` just looks up the type of expression and tries to convert it to `bool`. Is it right? To which object refers `this` inside `operator bool()`? Btw, wtf is `this + 1`? (`constexpr operator bool() { constant<true> v = *(this + 1); return x; }`) If it's UB why it allowed in constexpr function?

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic `*(this + 1)` need not be UB in all cases.  If the object is a member of an array, and you are not interacting with the last element, then `*(this + 1)` will just give you the next element in the array.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm referring to concrete code example (code in question + this comment). There is no arrays.

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic - A single object gets an exemption and may be regarded as an array of 1 element. So `this + 1` is okay. Not sure about `*(this + 1)` right now.

Comment: Some constant expressions are notionally evaluated at runtime, even if we know the value ahead of time, but it’s hard to argue that `x` is within its lifetime when a member function is called on it here.

Answer (score 1):

It works because this conversion to auto operator is constexpr.

```
template<auto x> struct constant {
    constexpr explicit operator auto() const { return x; }
};
```

It is called by the static_assert, even if marked explicit.  It looks like putting an expession within a static_assert is akin to making an explicit cast to bool.  The same is true for 'if' as in `if (registryv2<0>::x)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69792281/static-assert-evaluates-non-constant-expression#comment123371219_69795105